# Global.asax Application_Error не срабатывает

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Есть сайт, построенный на `MVC`, настроена обработка ошибок `http`-запросов через контроллер путём создания обработчика `Application_Error`. Локально всё отлично работает. Код в обработчике выполняется, контроллер выводит нужную вьюху с ошибкой. Но на удалённом сервере вызов `Application_Error` даже не происходит. Читал тут: [`Application_Error not firing when customerrors = “On”`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508415/application-error-not-firing-when-customerrors-on)
, но не помогло, `web.config` настроил как там писали, но вызов по-прежнему не происходит. Кто-нибудь может разъяснить с чем связана проблема и как её исправить?

Answer (score 1):

2 Варианта, локально тестили в релизи или только в дебаге? И наиболее вероятно проблемы с конфигом. Если делаете в MS VS, то попробуйте сделать publish, а протестировать через IIS локально но без студии.

Comment: Тестировал локально через иис, в дебаге. не вызывается. То есть фактически вызывается только когда генерится веб-сервер самой студией.

Comment: Под иис не работает вообще весь сайт или только обработка ошибок?

Comment: только обработка ошибок. конкретно вся логика лежит в Global.asax в обработчике Application_Error. Под иис этот обработчик не вызывается. И показывается страница иисовская.

Comment: Для проверки Global.asax попробуйте сделать мапинг на любой обработчик (через routes),  это позволит понять грузиться ли глобал вообще или нет

Comment: @zuev93, глобал грузится, все экшены замаппены через роутинг. я думаю что нужно как-настроить веб-конфиг, но не удаётся(